# How to track a new employee's activities in scrum template on TFS?

Tags: agile, tfs, burn-charts

From this question:
[How to factor in story points/tasks for non sprint related items?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/how-to-factor-in-story-points-tasks-for-non-sprint-related-items?rq=1)

I gather you would reduce the capacity to a new employee to probably 0 for a while untile they are up to speed after training, pc set up, etc. in order to maintain the velocity of burn down charts accurately.

However would you track their activities through work items in Team Foundation Server or would you just leave their capacity at 0 without any work items?

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, I don't think you want to reduce their capacity to 0. You know what you mean by that, and I know what you mean by that, but a senior stakeholder may not. Project Management is as much to do with managing your stakeholders, and their expectations, as anything else.

I'd suggest keeping the capacity to 25-50% of whatever normal capacity it, and book the rest of the time to training, if you have an account for that. Remember that every action should be tracked, even your noob scratching their head trying to make sense of the codebase. I'm not sure if you can track that in TFS, but if so go for it.

Hope that helps

Comment: so let's say I was to put 25%, my first question would be what do you tie that capacity to, what Work Item\Task? The rest of that 75% that is "missing", there would be no way to explain that in Team Foundation Server I take it?

Comment: I'm asking b/c our company wants full transparency through TFS as to what everyone on the team is doing - don't ask lol.